# Dual network system for home server rack

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, home-networking, home-server

I was redirected here for this question from Server Fault.

So I have a big project in mind, as I am developing a large project that requires a lot of memory, hardware, and massive amounts of separate servers. But i want to run this "testing beta" operation out of my house, and not colocate or anything. I have then decided to get 5-6 servers, and run OpenStack on them, to compensate for the need of lots of hardware.

The internet in my house is already pretty bad, with all of the physical obstructions to the signal, etc... So I was planning on wiring ethernet to key locations in the house. I am going to wire the COAX cable to the place in the house where the servers will go, wire all of the ethernet there, and connect it to the now-rackmount router, with access points at each key location.

The problem is, the servers just dont need a lot of internet, but I do use a lot of internet-intensive things outside of the rack, and i want to do something with media prioritization (which my router supports), and put my home ports above the servers.

To keep everything organized, I want to have a separate router & network that connects to all of the servers + switches, so that i can "down-prioritize" one internet device that connects to all of the servers.

Is all I have to do for this is change the server router ip to 10.0.1.1 instead of 10.0.0.1, and wire a Gigabit/cat5 cable between them? Or maybe assign a static private/public IP to the server network?

I am just wondering how complicated this will all be, and how I would most easily do this.

Thank you, and I apologize for writing a novel for this one question.
- BurnDownTheIgloo

Comment: Oh my... having a separate router and subnet for every server is overkill. You should invest in a router with bandwidth shaping amd connect everything through that. Then, if need be, you can separate the servers out with vlans. This would reduce the number of hops between the servers, and between the servers and the internet.

Comment: oh no, i must've not explained properly. one sub-network for ALL of the servers together. So: ISP> Modem > master router to house > slave router for servers & switch

Comment: CConard96's solution is far better. One device can do everything you ask. Get a router that offers port - based VLANs and/or then connect switches/managed switches where you can then manage which device is in which VLAN and manage the traffic priorities.